# How to display content over an HDMI cable from an old Android device to an external screen?

Tags: android, slideshow, android-2.3-gingerbread, hdmi

I have a very old Android 2.3.5 device (HTC Evo 4G) which has an HDMI cable connector.  I am interested in using the wired HDMI connection to mirror the phone's screen or otherwise display images on an external monitor.

I have developed a simple slideshow application, but I don't know how to get the images to show on the external display.

When the HDMI cable is connected, the monitor 'knows' something is there, but the external monitor screen is blank.  There used to be a tool on the play store (FullHDMI by TeamWin) that apparently allowed mirroring, but that tool is gone now.  I thought that if that source code were available, I could see if there was device specific code or learn more about what needs to be done to enable external displays.

What needs to be done in the Android code so that the content is displayed on the external monitor when that external monitor is connected via an HDMI cable?

Comment: There is no support in the Android SDK for this for Android 2.3. There is no support in Android proper for external monitors until Android 3.0, let alone at the SDK level. Devices that offered external display support prior to Android 3.0 did it themselves and usually just offered simple automatic screen mirroring. Whatever FullHDMI did would have to have been well outside the bounds of normal app development.

Comment: I looked on www.htcdev.com and couldn't find anything there that looked helpful.